# Table formatting

Tags: html, css

I have the below structure of the table. I tried adding empty tds divs, to get the below formatting in the image but not able to get it right. Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tR>    
    <td align="center"> <strong>ONE</strong></td> 

    <td align="center"><strong> TWO</strong></td>

    <td align="center"><strong>THREE</strong></td>
    </tR>

    <tr>
        <td align="left">Quiz NAME</td>
        <td align="right">FINAL</td>
        <td align="right">USS </td>
        <td align="right">PA </td>
        <td align="right">INTL </td>        
        <td align="right"> FINAL</td>
        <td align="right"> USS</td>
        <td align="right"> PA </td>
        <td align="right"> INTL </td>
        <td align="right"> FINAL</td>
        <td align="right"> USS</td>
        <td align="right"> PA</td>
        <td align="right">INTL</td>     
    </tr>
    <TR>DATA HERE</TR>

   </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Could the colspan attribute help?

Comment: Did any of answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to colspan to merge the columns in table. Update your table structure like below.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tR>    
<td colspan="4" align="center"> <strong>ONE</strong></td> 

<td colspan="4" align="center"><strong> TWO</strong></td>

<td colspan="4" align="center"><strong>THREE</strong></td>
</tR>

<tr>
    <td align="left">Quiz NAME</td>
    <td align="right">FINAL</td>
    <td align="right">USS </td>
    <td align="right">PA </td>
    <td align="right">INTL </td>        
    <td align="right"> FINAL</td>
    <td align="right"> USS</td>
    <td align="right"> PA </td>
    <td align="right"> INTL </td>
    <td align="right"> FINAL</td>
    <td align="right"> USS</td>
    <td align="right"> PA</td>
    <td align="right">INTL</td>     
</tr>
<TR><td colspan="12">DATA HERE</td></TR>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tR>    
<td colspan="4" align="center"> <strong>ONE</strong></td> 

<td colspan="4" align="center"><strong> TWO</strong></td>

<td colspan="4" align="center"><strong>THREE</strong></td>
</tR>

<tr>

    <td align="center"align="center">FINAL</td>
    <td align="center" >USS </td>
    <td align="center"align="center">PA </td>
    <td align="center">INTL </td>        

    <td align="center"> FINAL</td>
    <td align="center"> USS</td>
    <td align="center"align="center"> PA </td>
    <td align="center"> INTL </td>

    <td align="center"> FINAL</td>
    <td align="center"> USS</td>
    <td align="center"> PA</td>
    <td align="center">INTL</td>     
</tr>
<TR>DATA HERE</TR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;`

example:

```
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this page:

http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

;)

colspan and rowspan is what you are searching for :)